# multiple rows, different heights - equalize each row (JS)

Tags: javascript, css

I have different rows with 4 divs in it.
Have a look at the following snippet:

```
<div class="w-row">
    <div class="w-col w-col-3">
        <!-- lets assume this image has a height of 30px -->
        <img src="myimage.png">
    </div>
    <div class="w-col w-col-3">
        <!-- lets assume this image has a height of 40px -->
        <img src="myimage.png">
    </div>
    <div class="w-col w-col-3">
        <!-- lets assume this image has a height of 20px -->
        <img src="myimage.png">
    </div>
    <div class="w-col w-col-3">
        <!-- lets assume this image has a height of 60px -->
        <img src="myimage.png">
    </div>
</div>

<div class="w-row">
    <div class="w-col w-col-3">
        <!-- lets assume this image has a height of 20px -->
        <img src="myimage.png">
    </div>
    <div class="w-col w-col-3">
        <!-- lets assume this image has a height of 40px -->
        <img src="myimage.png">
    </div>
    <div class="w-col w-col-3">
        <!-- lets assume this image has a height of 20px -->
        <img src="myimage.png">
    </div>
    <div class="w-col w-col-3">
        <!-- lets assume this image has a height of 30px -->
        <img src="myimage.png">
    </div>
</div>
```

I want to equalize each row diffrently, so that in my 1st `w-row`, the container with the classes `w-col w-col3` should get a height of the maximum height of the elements in it. In my example, the 1st 4 divs in w-row therefore should get a height of 60px each.

The 2nd 4 divs should get a height of 40px

Usually I use a equalizer-function for that, but the content is rendered dynamically, so there are `n` elements and rows, so I can't just number them through, since I have to use the equalizer something like this:

```
equalizeHeight("w-row w-col-3") // this would lead to having all columns to have the highest image-height of all elements on the page
```

if I use it something like this:

```
equalizeHeight("w-row w-row1"), I'd have to call this function `n` times, without knowing how many times it has to be called.
```

Anyone an idea / solution?

// Update 1

Link to the CSS-file 
[webflow.css](http://pastebin.com/wyKrsWh5)

Comment: Can you share the CSS ? maybe you can just use table-cell or flexbox on CSS

Comment: @DaniP added the webflow.css in a pastebin.

Comment: Can you use flexbox? Also, please include the **relevant** CSS **in** your post. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The cleanest solution its to use `flex-box`. It will equalize all the heights without the need to "tablify" the columns.

```css
.flex-row{
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
    -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
  }


.flex-col{
   padding:5px;
   display: -webkit-flex;
   display: -ms-flexbox;
   display: flex;
  }

 p{
   background-color:black;
   color:#fafafa;
   padding:5px
  }
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="row flex-row">
  <div class="col-xs-3 flex-col">

    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. </p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-3 flex-col">

    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. </p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-3 flex-col">

    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-3 flex-col">

    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui offi</p>
    </div>
  </div>
```